# Spring Cloud CDC separate base class configuration

Tags: spring, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to set up a spring CDC configuration.

But I have a problem when I want to define separate base classes for mappings.

When I define it as

```
contracts {
    contractsDslDir.set(file("src/test/resources/contracts"))
    testFramework.set(org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.config.TestFramework.JUNIT5)
    packageWithBaseClasses.set("my.app")
}
```

it works.

But when I use the `baseClassMappings` element I get an exception.

```
contracts {
    contractsDslDir.set(file("src/test/resources/contracts"))
    testFramework.set(org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.config.TestFramework.JUNIT5)
//    packageWithBaseClasses.set("my.app")
    baseClassMappings {
        baseClassMapping("src/test/resources/contracts/one.*", "my.app.ContractVerifierBase")
    }
}
```

Error I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You haven't configured a MockMVC
> instance. You can do this statically
>
> RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(..) RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(..);
> RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(..);
>
> or using the DSL:

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

1. We need to set `packageWithBaseClasses` anyway.
2. BaseClass and package for tests should have same name

```
contracts {
    contractsDslDir.set(file("src/test/resources/contracts"))
    testFramework.set(org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.config.TestFramework.JUNIT5)
    packageWithBaseClasses.set("my.app")
    baseClassMappings {
        baseClassMapping("src/test/resources/contracts/user.*", "my.app.UserBase")
        baseClassMapping("src/test/resources/contracts/company.*", "my.app.CompanyBase")
    }
}
```